# Unity3d C# - Find second closest cube

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script to find the current closest cube:

```
GameObject FindClosestCube() {

    GameObject[] gos;
    gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cube");
    GameObject closest = null;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    float position = transform.position.z;
    foreach (GameObject go in gos) {
        float diff = go.transform.position.z - position;

        float curDistance = diff;
        if (curDistance < distance) {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Now I would like to get the second closest cube, so the closest cube after the closest cube (z-axis). I tried a few things, but they didn't work so could someone explain me how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Just before assigning a new closest, assign the current value of the closest to the second closest.
Then return an array of game objects, the first element being the closest.

```
GameObject[] FindClosestCubes() {
    GameObject[] gos;
    gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cube");
    GameObject closest = null;
    GameObject secondClosest = null;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    float position = transform.position.z;
    foreach (GameObject go in gos) {
        float diff = go.transform.position.z - position;

        float curDistance = diff;
        if (curDistance < distance) {
            secondClosest = closest;
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    return new GameObject[] { closest, secondClosest };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do get these errors: https://i.gyazo.com/b220c8d05abf69b83e57bdc8952e7619.png, I never made a line similair to ''GameObject[] { closest, secondClosest };" so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Jip1912 Sorry forgot about the **new** keyword in the return. I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks, but now I get this error: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject[]' to `UnityEngine.GameObject'

Comment: @Jip1912 yes, because we're now returning an array of GameObjects, please use the bracket syntax to refer to the objects. `FindClosestCubes()[0]` would be the closest, and `FindClosestCubes()[1]` would be the second closest.

Comment: Alright I understand. Now the code is acting a bit weird (this is my full code now: http://pastebin.com/mbmPB5CC)

As you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/XSmtqOR.gifv it doesn't show the right cubes (zoom out a little for a better resolution)

Comment: @Jip1912 the only potential fix I can see here is making sure is that positional difference is a positive value: `float diff = Mathf.Abs(go.transform.position.z - position)`. Other than that there are structural problems, like calling `FindGameObjectsWithTag ` in an update. You should just cache all objects in a list.

Comment: I made a list and used absolute values, but both didn't do the trick. I might use the list in a wrong way, but at the moment it looks like this https://pastebin.com/TFYXCFj8. The cubes are assigned in the inspector. When using a list, the debug just shows me the current cube i'm standing on.

Comment: @Jip1912 set the initial position as follows: `float position = cubes[0].transform.position.z`

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/e7ac6d7c61f318566a7dbc8a3ce871f4.png I did that, but 2nd cube returns nothing :/

Comment: Have you got an answer to that?

Comment: @Jip1912 Nope, sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway for helping. Maybe someone else knows an answer.